# how to plot filled.contour

Tags: r, contour

I am trying to do do a filled.contour graph, but at the end I got this error

```
"Error in .filled.contour(x, y, z, levels, col) : 
  no proper 'z' matrix specified".
```

I am using z as:

```
# A tibble: 21 × 9
   ...1  ...2         ...3  ...4    ...5     ...6        ...7  ...8  ...9
 * <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0   -0.0000122     0   0.416   0.0306   0.0000122     0     0
 2     0     0 -183.            0 283.    253.     183.            0     0
 3     0     0  -87.4           0  98.0    95.2     87.4           0     0
 4     0     0  -44.7           0  47.1    46.5     44.7           0     0
 5     0     0  -26.8           0  27.6    27.4     26.8           0     0
 6     0     0  -17.8           0  18.2    18.1     17.8           0     0
 7     0     0  -12.8           0  12.9    12.9     12.8           0     0
 8     0     0   -9.61          0   9.72    9.69     9.61          0     0
 9     0     0   -7.53          0   7.59    7.58     7.53          0     0
10     0     0   -6.07          0   6.12    6.10     6.07          0     0

y_A <- seq(-200,200,by=50) [1:9]
x_A <- seq(0,10000,by=500) [1:21]
```

Comment: Please use `\`\`\`` around code and data blocks to format them more readably

Comment: Could you please include the actual code you applied which resulted in the error?

Comment: Yes, I use the code that is presented in the description of the filled.contour help of Rstudio.

```
filled.contour(x = x_A,
               y = y_A,
               z,
               xlim = range(x, finite = TRUE),
               ylim = range(y, finite = TRUE),
               zlim = range(z, finite = TRUE))
```